# GDB in DDD produces a return character when I attempt to lookup value of variable

Tags: keyboard-layout, debugging, gdb

I've been trying to look up a value using `gdb` in `ddd`, in a .asm file as I am programming x86 assembly but when I type (into gdb) `x/uw &min` in the `gdb` shell, I just get a return character that resembles a logic negation symbol that has been tilted upward ninety degrees:

[offending character, click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9m9b.png)
So this is the image of the character that is produced when I tap the return (enter) key. As you can see in the image below, I tapped enter 4 times and no gdb output is produced.

[image: gdb issue image, click here]

My computer is an Evolve III maestro and my operating system is an amd64 Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I've tried looking at keyboard settings and making sure they're standard US settings. I really need this debugger to work properly so any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I see the error in the screen shot. I do not see the command that was used that caused the error. Please EDIT and add.

Comment: @David the command is x/uw &min but the return key won’t allow a value to be seen. Just a return key character.

Comment: Do not put that info in comments. As I suggested use the EDIT command and add that info to the question.

Comment: @David it’s been in the question since I originally posted it. Are you able to aid me in my current predicament my good sir?

Comment: Can you please copy the offending character and add it to your question so we can understand what it is? It's hard to read from the screenshot. Also, when does this character appear? When you press Enter? Some other key? Is your keyboard layout correctly recognized in the gdb shell? That is, do all characters appear as expected when you press the relevant key, especially those that need some key combination (e.g. shift+number key)?

Comment: Might this be of help? -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/61583077/3720510 -  NOTE: `min` is not "defined" in the image, if it is a pointer to a value you might need a different syntax, as it looks now you're printing the value at the address defined by `min` (C syntax expected, I'm not familiar with gdb).

Comment: As was noted, x/uw is not proper gdb syntax, use something like p x  then the "r"s are probably the output of the print newLine (a return character 0xd).  On a new machine, if you carried over an old .ddd directory, you might want to remove/delete it and let ddd remake it with the latest configs. And probably be running X instead of Wayland, haven't tested that yet.

Comment: @terdon I provided the return character image. And yes this only happens when I press "return" key. All other keys when pressed in conjunction with the shift key work just fine. I just can't seem to press "Enter" to get output from gdb

Comment: @Hannu min is defined in my program as "dd min 0" (define double word  <variable name> <variable value>) as this is a .asm file for x86 assembly language.

Comment: @ubfan1 so should I uninstall ddd and reinstall it? And make sure I delete all info in directories related to ddd? I believe I tried that already. Also I don't know what x or Wayland is.

Comment: No need to reinstall ddd, just delete the .ddd directory in your home directory.  That did fix up my 22.04 problems (haven't run ddd in awhile).  Wayland is the default for non-Nvidia drivers, so check at the login screen, after you select a user, before password, click on the gear icon in the lower right screen corner. Select the Xorg choice (or the ubuntu choice if the other choice is Wayland).

Comment: @ubfan1 I did everything you said but the bug still persists! gdb won't let me press Enter key without return character appearing. Xorg is better I see, on a side note, thanks.

Comment: `dd`as in define double? does that actually match `x/uw`? I'm just asking as a lead forward, *again I'm not familiar enough with either of x86/64 assemblers nor gdb (I've seen a lot of 68k though)*.

Comment: Check your edit/preferences/fonts, and the debugger setting.  Also, if you run gdb on your program in a terminal, does it work as expected or do you get the same errors you see in ddd. At the lower left corner, a triangle will pop up more gdb output/errors/info -- anything of interest?

Comment: @Hannu yes, they match. But the issue is that even if they didn't, I should still be able to press enter and produce something whether an error or a numerical value.

Comment: @ubfan1 I check preferences, fonts, and settings. Everything appears to be normal. When I run gdb in a terminal it works perfectly with no errors.

Comment: Look under ddd's edit/GDB Settings menu, and see what "Extended Prompt" is set to.  That may be the source of the odd character.  I tried running ddd under Wayland, and it failed to have the buttons work, although the source displayed and gdb commands worked.  Going back to X, ddd still failed (it was working) -- had to delete the ~/.ddd directory again, and a fresh start made ddd work again. Something fragile in the setup apparently.

Comment: I looked in the gdb settings and didn't see "Extended Prompt". I saw "GDB's prompt." which was in grey and set to "(gdb)" Where can I find extended prompt? The gdb settings are poorly organized as you basically just scroll through everything with no clear direction as to where to find things.